# Trouble defining "op" and "override" values in word problem

Tags: python, function

Does anyone know how to define the op value or the override value in this problem? I was having trouble figuring out how to actually type out the code and how to relate them to x and y.

`resultSolver(x: int, y: int, op: str, override: callable)->int`

Problem description:

> This function will expect 2 values, x, and y, which will be integers. It will also have two optional values op and override. this function is expected to return an integer. Op will be a string representing a mathematical operation ('+', '-', '*', '/') to be performed between x and y. If op is not defined it should default to addition. Override is a function that accepts two integers and returns an integer as a value. If override is not defined it this function should return the result of x and y computed with the op value. If override is specified this function should return the result of the invocation of override with x and y passed into it.

```
def resultSolver(x:int, y:int, op:str, override:callable)->int:

def op(defVal = '+'):
    str_in = input()
    str_in = str_in.strip()

    if not str_in and defVal:
        str_in = defVal

def override(x, y):


x = input()
y = input()
```

This is the code that I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem description is saying that these are values that you will be provided, not functions that you have to implement.

```
from typing import Callable, Optional

def resultSolver(
    x: int, 
    y: int, 
    op: str = "+",
    override: Optional[Callable[[int, int], int]] = None
) -> int:
    if override is not None:
        return override(x, y)
    # implement the rest!  You'll need to use the values of x, y, and op.
```

You do not need to write code for `override` (except maybe to test that your `resultSolver` function does the right thing with whatever `override` you pass it), and `op` is just a string that tells you what to do with `x` and `y`.

Some tests that might be useful:

```
assert resultSolver(6, 2, "+") == 8
assert resultSolver(2, 3, "*") == 6
assert resultSolver(9, 3, "/") == 3
assert resultSolver(5, 1, "-") == 4
assert resultSolver(2, 3, override=pow) == 8
```